# What does it mean one performs perfect and quickest Stroop tests?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

As part of a neuroplasticity training program a subject has to perform in various Stroop Effect tests. Such as:

- Color to color names
- Animal to animal names
- Position of a word within a square
- Number of words within a square

If the subject performs perfect in all tests, and is extremely fast, has no problem whatsoever to perform in this test (meaning that responses are equally fast as if colors/symbols matches their words/positions), what does that tell us about the subject's brain or neurology? What is its meaning in relation to cognitive functioning and what are some real-life implications that can be derived from such a performance in this test?

Comment: Most of these tests do not give great weight to the absolute reasction times, but rather the difference in reaction times. A lack of a difference in reaction time between congruent and incongruent pairs in a Stroop task would be concerning.